# Rails 2 route unknown to me when porting app to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-3-upgrade

I can't seem to figure out how to port this particular route from Rails 2 to 3:

```
map.resources :webservices, :new => { :push_data => :post, :reset_url => :post }
```

The relevant pastie is here: http://pastie.org/4022761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what you are trying to do.
You need to update your routes.rb file like so:

```
resources :webservices do 
    post :push_data, :on => :new
    post :reset_url, :on => :new
end
```

I did this to a model I have in a project called Notes, when I called rake routes, it gave me this:

```
push_data_new_note POST   /notes/new/push_data(.:format)        notes#push_data
reset_url_new_note POST   /notes/new/reset_url(.:format)        notes#reset_url
new_note           GET    /notes/new(.:format)                  notes#new
```

This should fix your route issue you were having.  Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: @PedroNascimento No problem.  Glad I was able to help.